# Eclipse cannot include boost/test/unit_test.hpp despite it being in the include path?

Tags: c++, eclipse, boost

In a source file I have

`#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>`

In the includes for the project I have

`/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.55.0/include`

I have verified that

`/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.55.0/include/boost/test/unit_test.hpp`

exists, but in spite of that, I still receive the error

`fatal error: 'boost/test/unit_test.hpp' file not found`

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to resolve this?

Comment: That include path looks rather strange. Anyway please show how exactly your project includes look like.

Comment: @VTT the include path is from installing boost with `brew`.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this problem I updated boost to 1.64.0 and removed all references to include boost.